# Coordinates of figure on array

Tags: matlab, coordinates, bounding-box

What is the shortest way to find coordinates of figure left/right/top/bottom edges? 4 coordinates (2 horizontal, 2 vertical lines) are enough.

Tried to flip, transpose, etc. My mind is gonna blow :/.

**[EDIT]:** Image is binary. Figure is represented by 1's.

[image: example figure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to get its bounding box with the [regionprops()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) function.

```
regionprops(img,'BoundingBox')
```

The result is (x,y) upper left coordinates x_width, y_width, size of the box.

I get `[45.5000000000000    45.5000000000000    174 107]` in your image.

Comment: Hmm. How did you get 174 and 107? :) It is shown, what image is 100x100pix large.

Comment: @s0upa1t Well, your original image migth be, but the image posted in this question is not. Try to rigth-click and save it and you'll see. Next time use imwrite to save images instead of saving the result of the plot.

Comment: I see what you did there. Btw, i'm not sure if StackOv-v supports any loseless image format. For this image, obviously, can be used almost every of them.

Comment: @s0upa1t PNG is supported

Answer (score 0):

The shortest solution i made:

```
% I - image array
V = sum(I,2);
edge_top = find(V,1,'first');
edge_bot = find(V,1,'last');
H = sum(I,1);
edge_left = find(H,1,'first');
edge_right = find(H,1,'last');
```